# Modelling Races

Tags: distributions, ordinal-data, ranking, games

The question that I wish to ask is what is an appropriate likelihood model to use for races.

For example, suppose that we have 4 competitors in a 100m race. We observe the competitors weight and age as input variables ($X$). The rank of the racer is observed as the output variable, $y$.

The first method that I chose to tackle the problem was as a classification problem. eg. map to a latent variable $f_{ir}=w^TX_{ir}$, and then use cross-entropy loss to get a MLE estimage of the weights. Here $w$ is a weight vector, $r$ is the $r$-th race and $i$ is the $i$-th competitor in that race.

**However, the problem is that a competitor with the same weight and age can come second in a different race, if there are better competitors**. This is what convinced me that this is not ordinal regression (which is what is used in rating systems).

An option to go around this is to let $f_{ir} = f_{ir} - \underset{{i\in r}}{\text{argmin}} \,\,f_{ir}$ so that the latent function is reset with respect to the weakest competitor. This brings us to a second problem. Since ordinal regression gives a threshold, $\theta_k$ on where the $k-th$ rank starts, this would expect gap between the weakest competitor and the strongest to be atleast $\theta_1$. Meaning that if the gap is small two players can be inferred to have rank two, since it did not surpass the thereshold.

Firstly am I looking at the problem wrong? Second if not what would be an appropriate likelihood to represent ranks within a race?

Comment: It seems difficult to rank competitors based on a couple of biological features and a single trial or race. You suggest that there is a 'different race' which implies multiple trials or races. Perhaps those multiple trials should be integrated into the model?

Comment: One classic model for rankings is the Plackett-Luce model. In general ranking problems can be viewed as permutation/matching problems, so it would be worthwhile to look into models for permutations.

Comment: Ironically I have a paper on this sort of problem due in 3 weeks, so will hopefully comment here with that, then.

Comment: @N. McA. : is the paper finnished?

Comment: I think I was referring to this. Not really sure how relevant it is. (future readers, sorry if I break this, I may do) https://n-mca.github.io/work/Nat_McAleese_Generic_Features_In_TrueSkill.pdf

Answer (score 0):

Google "learning to rank", "Optimizing for the AUC" or similar. One idea is to predict probability that person $i$ wins over person $j$ as

$NN(x_{ir},x_{jr})$ with $x_{ir}$ being features of subject $i$ at race $r$, NN some neural network or model. Ground truth is binary. Predicting who wins a race is then pairwise comparisons among all contestants (=ranking)

Related [[answer]](http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/199392/69416)

Comment: (1) you can use TeX math mode in this stack exchange (2) it's better to write abbreviations out (3) googling often leads to StackOverflow, so I suggest to rephrase it to "The idea of *learning to rank* is..."